# Android Studio Gradle Build Fail: Failed to notfify dependency resolution listener

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am tryıng to build my Android project with Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1, gradle version 8.3 and Android SDK 33. The gradle sync fails every time with the below error message:

```
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
'void org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions$Substitution.with(org.gradle.api.artifacts.component.ComponentSelector)
```

Here is a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mXja.png

Project build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: 'versions.gradle'
    addRepos(repositories)
    dependencies {
        classpath deps.android_gradle_plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    addRepos(repositories)
}

task clean(type: Delete){
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion build_versions.compile_sdk
    buildToolsVersion build_versions.build_tools
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion build_versions.min_sdk
        targetSdkVersion build_versions.target_sdk

        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.3.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled build_options.debug_mode_minify
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            debuggable build_options.debug_mode_debuggable
            jniDebuggable build_options.debug_mode_jniDebuggable
            renderscriptDebuggable build_options.debug_mode_renderscriptDebuggable
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled build_options.release_mode_minify
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.pro'
            debuggable build_options.release_mode_debuggable
            jniDebuggable build_options.release_mode_jniDebuggable
            renderscriptDebuggable build_options.release_mode_renderscriptDebuggable
        }

    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    ndkVersion ndk_settings.version
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation deps.app_compat
    implementation deps.preference
    implementation deps.security_crypto
    implementation deps.security_identity
    implementation deps.fragment
}
```